# Overriding default interface method with abstract method

Tags: java, overriding, abstract

I find it weird and was wondering if it is something that is regularly used. When can it be useful?

```
public interface InterA { 
   Object getInfo() throws Exception1; 
}
public interface InterB {
   public default Integer getInfo(Object s) {return 67;} 
}

public interface InterC extends InterA, InterB {
   @Override public abstract Integer getInfo(Object s);
}
```

Comment: You could test if this compiles using javac...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I did, it compiles. Is it regulary used, when is it useful?

Comment: Then your question should not be if this is allowed. You're asking for use cases to use this design. I recommend you to edit the question, otherwise the answer would be: **yes, it's allowed.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exists before default interface methods. For example, an abstract class can make

```
    @Override
    abstract public int hashCode();
```

forcing subclasses to provide implementations for `hashCode`, possibly because of additional requirements imposed by the abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you are allowed to do that. The name itself telling that it's `abstract`. You are allowed to do that where as the implemented class of that abstract class must override that method.

*When you decide to be an abstract, you need not to implement.*

Comment: So the class that implements InterC, lets say InterD, must give an implementation of the method? Let's then say that we have a InterE that implements InterD, can InterE make the method abstract again?