# Can we make a overridden method as abstract method in Java?

Tags: java

If I override a method from Parent class to child class then is it possible to make this child class overridden method as abstract?

Comment: Did you try? What Happen.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337498/overriding-default-interface-method-with-abstract-method (but not a duplicate)

Comment: I will never undertand why people ask questions on the Internet about things they could test for themseolves in thirty seconds.

Answer (score 5):

The Java Language Specification ([§8.4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.1)) states the following:

> *"An instance method that is not abstract can be overridden by an abstract method."*

Therefore, what you are trying to do is permitted.  For example:

```
public class Parent {
   public void method() { }
}

public abstract class AbstractChild extends Parent {
   public abstract void method();   // This is permitted.
}
```

<sup>The quoted text is taken from the Java 8 edition of the JLS, but to my knowledge, this has been true for all versions of Java from Java 1.0 onwards.</sup>

It is also permitted for an abstract method to override an abstract method.

It is also permitted to do this when `Parent` is an interface rather than a class, and even when `method` has a `default` implementation in an interface.

Comment: I've seen this kind of overriding employed to enforce `Object.toString()` overriding (since this method has to return a string representation of the current object, not of the parent's one.)

Comment: Yea, I've seen people do that. Not a good idea, IMO.  (And it doesn't actually force anything useful: for example, consider this implementation:  `ChildClass.toString() { return super.toString(); }` ... )

Comment: @StephenC `public abstract boolean equals();` & `public abstract int hashCode();` has some semantic use case. (also see java.lang.Record which does exactly this to provide a refined contract for those methods)